# VBOX_E_NOT_SUPPORTED on Dynamically Sized .vdi

Tags: virtualbox

I'm trying to resize a VM using the following:

```
$ VBoxManage modifyhd ff2d9746-0c51-42f6-995b-611e0b3bcc05 --resize 15000
  0%...
  Progress state: VBOX_E_NOT_SUPPORTED
  VBoxManage: error: Resize hard disk operation for this format is not implemented yet!
```

However, everything I can find about this error points to either not using a .vdi or not using a dynamically sized .vdi.

I am

```
UUID:           ff2d9746-0c51-42f6-995b-611e0b3bcc05
Parent UUID:    base
State:          created
Type:           normal (base)
Location:       /home/[username]/VirtualBox VMs/Server2/Server2.vdi
Storage format: VDI
Capacity:       15360 MBytes
```

and

```
$ VBoxManage showhdinfo 5dba2121-5dbf-4945-85e1-57aa66f7295d
  UUID:           5dba2121-5dbf-4945-85e1-57aa66f7295d
  Parent UUID:    base
  State:          created
  Type:           normal (base)
  Location:       /home/[username]/VirtualBox VMs/Server/Server/Server.vdi
  Storage format: VDI
  Format variant: dynamic default
  Capacity:       15360 MBytes
  Size on disk:   13218 MBytes
  In use by VMs:  SomeServer (UUID: d1a2a616-f2ff-4d95-9ade-e44c960d74b7)
```

Running the following version:

```
$ vboxmanage --version
  4.3.18r96516
```

Comment: @Ramhound I'm trying to increase the size.

Comment: @Ramhound And that's my problem. I thought it was +AMOUNT. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem ended up that I was trying to shrink the drive instead of increase it. The `--resize` amount is the final size, and is not added to the current size.

```
VBoxManage modifyhd ff2d9746-0c51-42f6-995b-611e0b3bcc05 --resize 30000
```

Comment: you might be able to help this guy http://superuser.com/questions/1020981/using-virtualbox-why-can-my-guest-win7-not-see-the-full-disk-size

Answer (score 2):

If you set your VDI properties as **Fixed** when initially setting up your VirtualBox image, it cannot be resized directly through VirtualBox.

You can however resize this via the command prompt using VBManage command in the VirtualBox folder.

Here is the link I used and it worked for me.
https://www.inspekt.dev/2021/04/13/how-to-resize-virtualbox-hard-disk-vdi-file-virtualbox-resize-hard-disk-error-vbox_e_not_supported/

Note that Virtual size can be resized but actual size remain the same

Comment: Unfortunatelly, size on disk C:\ remains the same as it was.

Comment: worked perfect on a fixed size Ubuntu 18.04 image. TY. was able to resize with this.

Answer (score -1):

For me I was trying to match the new value that I had set inside the Virtual Media Manager to the `resize` parameter in MB, just adding an extra GB of MBs to that value made it work.

Comment: This really should have been a comment to the accepted answer, indicating, that you only have to slightly increase the size of the VM for it to work.

Answer (score -1):

I tried to fight my way through this as well.

In the end I used a free Version of AOMEI Partition assistant and resized C. inside the Windows VirtualBox

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).