# Using Virtualbox, why can my guest (Win7) not see the full disk size?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox

I need to extend my `Windows7.vdi`. I tried:

```
$ VBoxManage modifyhd /mnt/data/VirtualBox/Windows7.vdi --resize 50000
```

but got: `Progress state: VBOX_E_NOT_SUPPORTED` - I read that this is due to fix file size but I know my file is dynamic. The file currently is 23.6GB in size but the Virtual Media Manager in VirtualBox tells me its “Virtual size” is 488.28GB but in Windows I can’t see that space, under Disk Management I only see my `C:` drive to have a capacity of 24.90GB. What's the problem here?

Oh yes the remaining space on my host disk is > 65GB, hence that should not be the limit.

Here’s a screenshot of the Disk Management dialog in Windows next to the Virtual Media Manager from VirtualBox:

[image]

If you look at the screenshot, no empty space is being made available on my disk. It won’t let me either create a new partition nor does it let me enlarge the existing one for some reason...

Comment: Your current syntax is trying to **shrink** the virtual driver by the way, which is not supported by Vbox, and didn't fully read the question so disregard my comment.

Comment: @Ramhound yes, if VirtualBox knows that my disk is supposed to be `488.28GB` but Windows can't see that. How can I make it visible to `Windows`? It only sees `24.90GB` (thus my intention to increase it to `50GB`)

Comment: **Your current syntax is trying to set the new size to 50GB instead of 500GB.**

Comment: **I know**! What I want is more than `24.90GB` - why does Windows limit me at `24.9GB`???

Comment: You cannot shrink a virtual disk with vbox manager so set it **correctly**

Comment: [The tool you are using does not know what size your virtual drive is, just that it is larger then 50GB, which is the reason you are getting `VBOX_E_NOT_SUPPORTED`](http://superuser.com/questions/848753/vbox-e-not-supported-on-dynamically-sized-vdi).  *Until you try the correct command, and report those results,  I cannot help*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you use the right number in your command to enlarge the disk:

Increasing the *disk* does not make the C: *partition* larger, it just makes the underlying *disk* larger. Inside Windows, you could now create a D: drive on the extra space, or extend the C: drive to encompass the extra space you gave the disk.

Comment: Please see **EDIT1** above, Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you enlarging the disk that you are using? That's the only idea I now have - check in the 'Settings' of the Virtual machine which hard disk it is really using. And of course you need to reboot your virtual machine after the change, but you probably did that.

Comment: Yes, under Settings/Storage/Controller: SATA/Windows7.vdi, it says "Location: /mnt/data/VirtualBox/Windows7.vdi" which is the same path as the one in the screenshot above. Yes, I definitely have rebooted my vm.

Comment: Then I have no more ideas, sorry... it worked right that way for me when I did that in the past. :-/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (Virtualbox 5.1.12 on Lubuntu 16.04 host with Windows 7 guest). 
It turned out that having snapshots complicated things a bit. I found that applying the "vboxmanage modifyhd ..." command to all snapshot .vdi's and the base .vdi solved the problem for me.
The Windows 7 guest disk management now showed empty space which I could use to extend the existing partition.
Only the last snapshot file will actually grow when you use the extra disk space. (I'm not sure if I really need to resize all .vdi's, but from another discussion [https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=64237] I guessed that it would be safer to have consistent disk size for all .vdi's).